# Using tooltips with Bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I've spent the last hour or so checking out every question I could find on how to get Bootstrap 3's tooltips working.

I've managed to get regular, unstyled tooltips working, but I really want that bootstrap look.

I know there's already been a lot of discussion on this, but I think it would be really helpful to have a step-by-step guide on exactly how to get tooltips working, as it seems to me that lots of people (myself included) are having issues getting it up and running.

Just FYI I'm running on a Java web server so all of my front-end is JSP.

Thanks, and have a good one ya'll.

Comment: maybe you can post what you have tried? (the code)

Comment: Hey @Jason, I appreciate the quick response. I think it would be even better to have a step-by-step guide on how to do it. I tried probably half a dozen ways of doing it, I can post one if you'd like, but if you know how to do it I'll be sure to confirm a well-written answer :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/31/):

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" id="right" title="" data-original-title="Tooltip on right">Tooltip on right</button>

<button type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" id="left" class="btn btn-default">Tooltip on left</button>

$(function(){
    $('#right').tooltip();
    $("#left").tooltip({
        placement: "left",
        title: "tooltip on left"
    });
});
```

More tooltip options are [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips).

Notice that you will have to add the tooltip handler in Javascript.

Comment: Hey thanks man, do you think you could talk about how to add the tooltip handler, I think that's what I'm doing improperly.

Comment: What doesn't work for you? Are you getting any error's in your console? Tooltip handler needs to be added in Javascript. Since, bootstrap is dependent on Jquery, you must first load Jquery then bootstrap. Then on Jquery's onready(), a.k.a $(). You need to add the tooltip handler as shown in the above fiddle.

Comment: I did all that but it still isn't working. Do you think you could show me exactly how you're including JQuery and all the plugins?

Comment: I just realized that I forgot to actually link the fiddle. I did it now. If you still have questions inspect fiddle source. This is how I include my scripts:



<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

notice that jquery needs to load before bootstrap.

Comment: Great, thanks again @Yogesh, just confirmed your answer. The includes are absolutely key – jquery before bootstrap.js, all in <script> tags.

Comment: I am not sure if you had read bootstrap's documentation, but they have mentioned it clearly on their getting started page that JQUERY is required. http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template. I would suggest to read through the getting-started page once.

Comment: I realize that Yogesh, and I have. It was a small error I made in the way I was including JQuery.

Answer (score 3):

#### My HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="mytooltip" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="tooltip" title="my tooltip"> tooltip </a>
```

#### My jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#mytooltip').tooltip();
});
```

Now just add the attribute: `data-placement="left"` like this:

```
<a href="#" id="mytooltip" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="tooltip" title="my tooltip" data-placement="left"> tooltip </a>
```